# Rails 5.2 to 6.0 upgrade issues with migration namespacing: uninitialized constant errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

Am having an issue with a `NameError Exception: uninitialized constant` error inside migrations that reference ActiveRecord models.  These same issue are not present in the console, so I am a little stumped as to what is happening in the migration that is different from in the rails console.

Basically, my ActiveRecord models do not seem to be autoloading everything correctly.

Here is an example of a simple call that works in the console but raises an error in the migration:

```rb
migration(byebug)> Customer.all
*** NameError Exception: uninitialized constant Customer (call 'Customer.connection' to establish a connection)::Querier
Did you mean?  Numerizer

nil
```

This same call, in the console, works.

Interestingly, if I first call another model that *does* load correctly (e.g., `MyOtherThing.all`), then if I next attempt to call to `Customer.all` no longer throws an error.

Just a little stumped as to where to begin to look for what's causing this.  Thanks!

Comment: FWIW, once you call Model.connection on any model, all models in that database will be connected. Doesn’t answer your question but should explain the one issue you raised.

Comment: Ah, interesting.  If I make the same `Customer.connection('select * from customers')` two times in a row, the first time raises an error the next time it works.  Not sure what that tells me ...

Comment: Not sure if this will be helpful. I'm having autoloading issues since upgrade to rails 6. Sometimes switching to `config.autoloader = :classic` helps. Switching back does not bring back the issue (it comes back after some time anyway). We're using bootsnap, and I run every command with `DISABLE_BOOTSNAP=1` which gives me bigger success rate. I don't have any fix, not better workarounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being a known issue:

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/37748

Hopefully it will be fixed soon.  And, part of my confusion had to do with dealing with `byebug` which was confusing me in terms of what was causing the real error.